# What is the proper way to prevent bindings and directives from being visible for the split second before angular is loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When my app loads, angular directives and bindings are visible for a slight moment before Angular consumes them. This is distracting and looks unprofessional, and I fear it may leave an unpleasant mark on my visitors.

What is the proper way to avoid this, besides the obvious solution of putting the Angular loading script into the head and blocking the render of the rest of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use ngCloak  directive

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Answer (score 3):

You should use either ngBind or ngCloak.

See [ngBind API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBind) / [ngCloak API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak)

Comment: Also, with ngCloak take note to include angular.js in the head OR include ng-cloak style in a CSS that is in head.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Try the ng-cloak directive. Docs state is just for this situation. I've used it without loading angular in the head as well.